# how to get value of a static placeholder in view.py

Tags: placeholder

How to get current value of a static placeholder in view.py.

In template I put invisible static placeholder "email"
I need is to be able to change it in the admin
in view.py need to send an email to this email address

Comment: Many people will have no idea what you're talking about. Please explain your question more thoroughly and give readers a context. I can only assume you're asking about Django and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i'm talking about django. I'm looking for something to store a single config value, that i can change it in admin panel